# Model Form extra fields

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models

So I have the added an extra field to a form through a model, & using these choices:

```
A_CHOICES = (
    ('none', 'none'),
    # further conversion table

class MyForm(ModelForm):

extra_field_a = ChoiceField(choices=A_CHOICES)
```

If this field is not 'none' then I want to use its value for a field in the model, but i'm unsure how to retrieve it, I tried within `MyForm`:

```
def cleaned_extra(self):
    if(self.cleaned_data.get('extra_field_a') != 'none'):
        return self.extra_field_a
    else:
        return self.original_field
```

But I get a NameError, 'global name not defined'? Any help much appreciated,

Adam

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly how you would retrieve it. Funky syntax aside, where is the `NameError`? `self` is undefined? Where did you put this code.

You would generally place this type of field specific code in the `clean_FOO` methods.
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation

```
def clean_extra_field_a(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data.get('extra_field_a')
    if data != 'none':
        return data
    return None # remember to set this field as required=False

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # override save to do something with your extra field.
    self.instance.myfield = self.cleaned_data.get('extra_field_a')
    super(MyForm).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

Update: Saving in the view is no problem.

```
mymodel = myform.save(commit=False) 
# ModelForm's will return the object being created/edited on save()
# commit=False will prevent a database save

mymodel.myfield = myform.cleaned_data.get('extra_field_a')
mymodel.save()

# note if you have an m2m, there is an extra method to call on commit=False
```

Comment: oh sorry- still making a long and painful transition from PHP, I had made a blundering error elsewhere. & was trying to save in the view, rather than the def save you've just pointed out.

Comment: saving in the view isn't a problem, as long as you remember to pull out the data from your extra field, as your `ModelForm` has no idea what to do with it. Let me update with an example of saving in the view